# Running karate test suite with JBang

Tags: karate

I would like to run my karate test suite using JBang both in CI env and locally. I see there is support for this but I have an error when I run the command

```
karate -g <PATH_TO_KARATE_CONFIG_JS> <PATH_TO_KARATE_FEATURE_FILES_FOLDER>
```

I have a global variable "baseUrl" defined in karate-config.js but it does not seem to be initialised with jbang, the error returned:

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "baseUrl" is not defined
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
```

Is anyone running the entire test suite using JBang??

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the JVM parameter to set the location of the config JS: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#karate-configjs

```
java -Dkarate.config.dir=parentdir/somedir -jar karate.jar my-test.feature
```

Or if you know how to set the Java classpath, add "." to it, so the run-time will look at the root directory (or where you have placed `karate-config.js`)

If you need hints on how to work with jBang, see this thread: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-npm/issues/9

Also note that a `-g` / `--configdir` param should also be supported.

Comment: I have tried all of the above but no joy. Would it be possible to target a JUnit runner class like this https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-junit5/src/test/java/karate/SampleTest.java invoked via a JBang command?

Comment: @QAdw sorry I give up. maybe you should use Docker plus a container with maven installed

Comment: Ok thanks either way, I will keep playing with it and update this if I get it resolved